# Gem Ransack doesn't return any results when searched with full name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using Ransack with Rails 3.

My views:

```
  <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name_or_last_name_or_company_cont, :style => 'width:150px;padding-top:6px;' %><p class="button">
    <%= f.submit "Search by name or company" %></p>
  <% end %>
```

My schema:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",                  
    t.string   "last_name"
```

on the User model I have:

```
  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
```

Working on the console.

If I have user with `first_name = "Foo"`, `last_name = "Bar"` , when I search with either one, I get the results as expected.

When I search with `full_name = "Foo Bar"`, I get no results.

I tried changing my text_field for Ransack to:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name_or_last_name_or_company_or_full_name_cont
```

I get `first_name_or_last_name_or_company_or_full_name_cont is undefined`

is there a quick way to solve this without adding another column for full_name on my users table?

also :

```
     7: def index
     8:   search_params = params[:q]
 =>  9:   binding.pry

[1] pry(#<UsersController>)> search_params
=> {"first_name_or_last_name_or_company_cont"=>"Foo Bar"}
```

I guess I can split key value here to search the first name only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a `Ransacker`. Add this in your `User` model:

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
    parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name])
end
```

You can check the [Ransack GitHub wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers#5-search-on-a-concatenated-full-name-from-first_name-and-last_name-several-examples) to more examples.

Comment: Thanks for point me in the right direction. Your example didn't work with mysql. I followed your link and tried an example there that did work. That is: ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws',
    [' ', parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name]])
end

Comment: Are you using mysql? because i tried the same and got no luck.

Comment: @JacobFrye Check the code in curts comment above yours. Maybe it will work for you too

Comment: Thank you. However, I have tested it with Rails 4.2 and PostgresSQL and there is a problem if you search for the first name and last name separated by space. Example: `first_name` is 'John', `last_name` is 'Doe'. If we search for only 'John' or only 'Doe', it works. However, if we search for 'John Doe', it will not find anything. We need to add the space character in the Ransacker. I'll create and answer illustrating it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your model:

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
      parent.table[:first_name], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')
    ),
    parent.table[:last_name]
  )
end
```

... and the following in your view:

```
<%= f.label :full_name %><br>
<%= f.search_field :full_name_cont %>
```

The ransacker part was taken from the [Ransack wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#5-search-on-a-concatenated-full-name-from-first_name-and-last_name-several-examples).

Tested on Rails 4.2 with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41898820/4174897) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: @Kyll: Sorry about that. I have done as you suggested.