# Searching by full name with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Ransack form on a project I inherited that looks like this:

```
<%- ransack_form_options ||= {} -%>
<%- search_field_options ||= {} -%>
<%- search_field_options.merge! autocomplete: "off", id: "q" -%>

<div class="search-form">
  <%= search_form_for(@q, ransack_form_options) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field search_on, search_field_options %>
    <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
    <%= button_tag '', class: 'cancel-search' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The value of `search_on` is `student_first_name_or_student_last_name_or_student_email_cont`.

This works for searching by first name or by last name or by email. But what if I want to search for *full name* or first name or last name or email? How can I do that?

Comment: what is `full_name` another db column or first_name + last_name? what database are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gem Ransack doesn't return any results when searched with full name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890665/gem-ransack-doesnt-return-any-results-when-searched-with-full-name)

Answer (score 7):

**Searching full_name with ransack (first_name & last_name)**

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CONCAT_WS', [
     Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' '), parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name]
  ])   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something like:

```
  ransacker :full_name do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(
      '||',
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(
        '||',
        parent.table[:first_name], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')
      ),
      parent.table[:last_name]
    )
  end
```

That will go in your model, and then in your view you can write full_name_or_first_name_or_last_name or whatever you wanted to write. I realize this is 3 years late, but hopefully this can be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Today it can be done easier:

```
ransacker :full_name do
  Arel.sql("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name)")
end
```

When has join table:

```
ransacker :user_name_with_contry_code do
  Arel.sql("CONCAT_WS(' | ', countries.code, users.first_name)")
end
```

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions mentioned, you'll also need to update ransackable_attributes.

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(_auth_object = nil)
 %w[fname lname phone_number full_name]
end
```

then you can use it

```
ransack(full_name_or_fname_or_lname_ ...
```